# How can I convert a DataStream of Avro SpecificRecord to Flink's RowData in Apache Flink 1.17.0?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, avro, delta-lake

Using scala 2.12.17 I am trying to convert an Apache Flink 1.17.0 DataStream of Avro `SpecificRecord` (org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord) to a DataStream of Flink's `RowData` (org.apache.flink.table.data.RowData) such that I can write the avro messages to storage using the Apache Flink Delta Connector ([Apache Flink Delta Connector](https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/blob/master/flink/README.md)), which needs the `RowData` format to be able to write. Additionally, I also need to get the associated `RowType` (org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType) of the `RowData` to supply to the Delta Connector writer method.

I have tried to use `AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema` (org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema) to do the conversion from a DataStream of `SpecificRecord` to a DataStream of `RowData` but I cannot wrap my head around how to do it in a generic way where I can do the conversion for any compiled avro schema of type `SpecificRecord` and at the same time get the associated `RowType`.